# Changing class on <P> or <DIV> with XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I need to turn `<P class="brodtext">` into `<P class="normal">` using XSLT.

I've started with:

```
<xsl:template match="//p[@class='brodtext']">
    </xsl:template>
```

Can you please advise on how to do the change?

Edit:

I need to integrate it into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:proxy="java:senselogic.sitevision.portlet.proxy.web.ProxyFunctions"
   extension-element-prefixes="proxy">

   <xsl:import href="template.xsl"/>
   
   
   <!-- H1-H6 needs newline -->
  <xsl:template match="h1">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">display:inline</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="h2">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">display:inline</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="h3">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">display:inline</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="h4">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">display:inline</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="h5">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">display:inline</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="h6">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">display:inline</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
   
      <xsl:template match="//@shape"/>
      <xsl:template match="//@clear"/>


  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@class[.='brodtext' and parent::P]">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">normal</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

   
 <!-- Visa -->  

 <!--  <xsl:template match="//div[@id='svid10_44e5251f1752aa6808f1edfa']"/>  -->
   
 <!-- Dölj -->  
   
 <xsl:template match="//div[@id='svid10_44e5251f1752aa6808f1edfb']"/>
     
      <xsl:template match="/"  >
     <xsl:apply-templates select="//div[@id='svid10_44e5251f1752aa6808f1edf8']"  />
   </xsl:template>
   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hmm... too much code to publish? I guess I have to write something else then.

That's odd.

Man, I don't know what to do, I'm sorry for spamming.

sdfoiu spdfoiu gposdifu fgu posid fui gposi duffgpoisu dfgpoisu dfpogiu sdpfofgpoiu spdofifgui psodifufgui psodifufgu posidfuoifgu posidufi g posiud fpgoisu dfpgoius dpfoigiu psodifusgu posidfu fgu posiduf g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it simply like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@class[.='brodtext' and parent::P]">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">normal</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMo5/1

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I need to implement it into my code, I added it in the original post. I'm sorry for not posting it right away, I didn't think it would matter. But apparently it did. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I tried to add this part: 

`
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@class[.='brodtext' and parent::P]">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">normal</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>`

Comment: @Ace2099 Update your original question. Post your input (a representative part of it) and you required output.

Comment: I've added my my code, I just want to add code into it so that it also changes the class name. Your code example looked like it would work. But when I added it into my code it didn't execute the change. The class was still "brodtext".

I've added your code into my code as I tried it now.

Comment: In your input file is the P element upper-case or lower-case? If it's lower-case then you need parent::p instead of parent::P.

Comment: YES!! That was it! Man I feel stupid now. Thank you so, SO MUCH! :D

Comment: Great. If it works, then please mark the answer as Accepted.